# Does "to be on the surface" mean to make something known to the public?

Tags: expressions, idioms, expression-choice

Can I use the expression "be on the surface" to mean that somebody finally makes himself known to the general public?

For example

> They have been ignored so far by the public, but they are now using the Sewol Ferry tragedy to finally be on the surface.

Comment: 'Be on the surface' is not a usual metaphor to use in such a case. I would probably say '..., but they are now using the Sewol Ferry tragedy to attract public attention to themselves'.

Comment: Well, there's "to be on the down low," so why can't there be "to be on the up high"? Sounds logical to me . . . sort of.

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: It's slightly colloquial, but I would be more inclined to say something like:  "They have been ignored so far by the public, but they are now using the Sewol Ferry tragedy to *come out of the closet*."  

"On the surface" generally means "superficially" or "unexpectedly".  That's not what you intend.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues here:

1. You would just say "to surface" or "to come to the surface", not "to be on the surface", like so:

> They have been ignored so far by the public, but they are now using the Sewol Ferry tragedy to finally come to the surface

or

> They have been ignored so far by the public, but they are now using the Sewol Ferry tragedy to finally surface

2. Typically, [surfacing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surface) implies something that was intentionally hidden, was forgotten, or was a surprise, not that it was trying to be visible but failing. Since you say "they have been ignored so far", it sounds like they were trying to be seen and failing.

Instead of "surface", try "gain recognition":

> They have been ignored so far by the public, but they are now using the Sewol Ferry tragedy to finally gain recognition

Examples of times "surface" would be appropriate:

- After years of solitude, she finally surfaced.
- The long-forgotten evidence surfaced at a most inconvenient time.

*Edit*: 
For completeness, "to surface" can also be very literal, such as a diver surfacing in a pool.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know that "to surface",or "come to the surface" imply that some was hidden somewhat intentionally hidden. "gain recognition" sound very appropriate in this context. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your choice of words in this situation requires some care, since the words you use may strongly influence whether readers are inclined to interpret the actions of the previously ignored individuals as cynically opportunistic or admirably public spirited. If you say

> They have been ignored so far by the public, but they are now exploiting the Sewol Ferry tragedy to gain exposure and publicity.

the individuals sound quite cold and calculating, because they are being described as taking advantage of the tragedy to pursue their own agenda. But if you say

> They have been ignored so far by the public, but owing to public interest in the Sewol Ferry tragedy, they are finally gaining a significant level of visibility [or "of public attention"].

they sound concerned and honest, because in this scenario the attention has come to them naturally rather than their having opportunistically sought to attract it following a calamitous event.

In either case you wouldn't want to use the phrase "on the surface" to mean "publicly recognized and paid attention to." The most common idiomatic sense of "on the surface" is (I believe) "at the level of mere appearances, but not necessarily when understood in greater depth."

Answer (score 0):

You would not use that expression this way, as it more closely refers to "be obvious", rather than be seen. You could say "to go public".